# Cloudant Lucene index with different relevance per field

Tags: cloudant

How can I specify during the index creation that one field should receive more relevance than another field?

Example: I have documents with a title and a description field and want the content of the title field to be more important during query time.

doc1: title:"Hello, world", description:"Just a greeting"
doc2: title:"Greetings", description:"Hello, everybody. Hello, hello"

index("default", doc.title);
index("default", doc.description);

A search for the term "hello" should return doc1 one with a higher relevance than doc2 because the word "hello" is present in the title field even though doc2 contains the word 3 times.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a boost at *query time* e.g. if you index items separately

```
index("title", doc.title);
index("description", doc.description);
```

Then at query time your can specify that the title gets more weight than the description field

```
q=(title:hello)^100 OR (description:hello)
```

where `^100` indicates that this term is boosted. See https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html#query-syntax

Comment: Thanks, Glynn. This sounds like an option. Of course my default index uses data from more than 10 different fields which makes a query pretty lengthy when I have to add them all.    Maybe something like this can work:  `q="hello" OR (title:"hello")^100`

Comment: Yes, Glynn, this works well for single words but gets quickly complex with multiple search terms.

`q=hello world OR ((title:hello)^100 OR (title:world)^100)`
Unless I search for an exact string I have to split them into individual field-term combinations. Otherwise only the first word is used for the field-specific seacrh.

Comment: It should be  `q=hello AND world OR ((title:hello)^100 AND (title:world)^100)`

Comment: my example was showing how you could boost a match in one field (the title) rather than in another. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The idea is to search in the default field for all entered words but add boost to the 'title' field. If a user searches for 5 words I need to repeat the field-specific query part 5 times to actually boost documents that have these 5 words in the title field.